# memory allocation for local static and local variable

Tags: c, unix

1.

```
void main(void)
{
  int *ptr1;
  ptr1 = (int *)malloc(..);
}
```

2.

```
void main(void)
{
  static int *ptr2;
  ptr2 = (int *)malloc(..);
}
```

I want to ask how is memory allocation done for ptr1 & ptr2?

Comment: In C, casting the return value of `malloc` is not necessary. Also, `void main(void)` should be at least `int main(void)`.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev why is it not necessary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ptr1` pointer itself is allocated on the stack. `ptr1` points to memory on the heap.

The `ptr2` pointer itself is allocated on program startup (before `main` is invoked) and is global but just happens to be visible only in `main` because it is declared in its scope. `ptr2` points to memory on the heap as well.

Declaring `ptr2` outside of `main` would only make it visible in all functions below it, but its storage will be the same.

Comment: even if i make ptr2 global will it have same effect as that of now

Comment: If you declare `int *ptr2;` outside of `main`, it will be the same except that `ptr2` will be visible in all the other functions below it, not just `main`.

Comment: @sourabh: Just to remind you because you are a new SO user, you are supposed to accept an answer by clicking the tick on the left.