# C's printf doesn't print a string (char array) out

Tags: c, string, printf

My question is basically using printf print a char array.

In some cases, it prints the result out:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* orig = "@reveals#?the treasure chest#$President Barack H. Obama#";
  printf("The input: %s\n", orig);
  printf("The output: %s\n", reArrange(orig));

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

sometimes not:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* orig = "@reveals#?the treasure chest#$President Barack H. Obama#";
  printf("%s\n", reArrange(orig));

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here is the complete code (the main function is included):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SUBJECT '$'
#define ACTION '@'
#define OBJECT '?'
#define END '#'

char* reArrange(char* orig) {
  int origSize = strlen(orig);

  char subject[origSize], action[origSize], object[origSize];

//int i;
//for(i = 0; i < origSize; i++) {
//  subject[i] = ' ';
//  action[i] = ' ';
//  object[i] = ' ';
//}
  int subjectIndex = 0,   actionIndex = 0,  objectIndex = 0;

  int timesEndCharShowUp = 0;

  char state;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < origSize; i++) {
    char ch = orig[i];

    if(ch == SUBJECT) {
      state = SUBJECT;
    }
    else if(ch == ACTION) {
      state = ACTION;
    }
    else if(ch == OBJECT) {
      state = OBJECT;
    }
    else if(ch == END) {
      if(timesEndCharShowUp == 3) {
        break;
      }
      else {
        timesEndCharShowUp++;
      }
    }
    else {
      if(state == SUBJECT) {
        subject[subjectIndex++] = ch;
      }
      else if(state == ACTION) {
        action[actionIndex++] = ch;
      }
      else if(state == OBJECT) {
        object[objectIndex++] = ch;
      }
    }
  }

  subject[subjectIndex] = '\0';
  action[actionIndex] = '\0';
  object[objectIndex] = '\0';

  char rearranged[origSize];
  sprintf(rearranged, "%s %s %s.\0", subject, action, object);
  //printf("%s\n", rearranged);

  orig = rearranged;
  return orig;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* orig = "@reveals#?the treasure chest#$President Barack H. Obama#";
//  printf("The input: %s\n", orig);
//  printf("The output: %s\n", reArrange(orig));
  printf("result: ");
  printf("%s\n", reArrange(orig) );
//fflush(stdout);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs two parameters:

```
char* reArrange(char* orig)
```

Should be:

```
char* reArrange(char *rearragned, char* orig) {

// make your magic here!

}
```

Calling sequence:

```
char input[SIZE];
char rearrange [SIZE];

// initialize everything! Don't forget to rearrange[0] ='\0\;!!!

rearrange(rearranged, input);

// do you printing....
```

You should also learn how to use pointers correctly and look up "switch".

Comment: `rearrange[0]` needs no initialisation in this case, though you might choose to do so.

Answer (score 5):

You are returning a pointer to memory that resides on the stack. `rearranged` is not available after the enclosing function (`reArrange`) returns and may contain garbage.

You may want to `malloc` `rearranged` or declare it globally.

Comment: @Clifford: `static` really means global but visible only in the enclosing function.

Comment: I see, but why `printf("The input: %s\n", orig);printf("The output: %s\n", reArrange(orig));`works?

Comment: When it works, you are lucky. Learn how the stack works and what is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Blagovest: No not at all!  Global variables are implicitly `static`, the converse is not true. `static` allocation is about the *lifetime* of a variable, globality on the other hand is about visibility and scope - if it has local scope it is by definition *not* global.  Of course by the time you have returned a non-`const` pointer to it, any protection obtained from making it local is largely lost.  Rudy's solution is the better and more usual one in any case.

Comment: I cannot believe 6 votes for suggesting the use of a global! [Required reading](http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/break-point/4025723/A-pox-on-globals); forget that it refers to embedded systems; the principles apply, err... *globally* ;)

Comment: @Clifford: I used "global" with a slightly different meaning - at the language level it is indeed imprecise to say it is global, but at the machine level the variable would go in the `data` or `bss` segment in either case.

Comment: @Blagovest: `static` is a storage class specifier, so yes it will be stored in the same segment perhaps as global data, but that is because global data is also static, not because static data is global.

Comment: @Clifford: OK, point taken. You may want to downvote another of my answers as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814940/memory-allocation-for-local-static-and-local-variable/5814979#5814979 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of only returning a `char *`, make `reArrange()` accept a buffer to which it can write the result. Now the caller must provide a suitable buffer to your function, and you have no problems with memory management anymore. You merely strncpy() arranged to the buffer. To be sure the buffer is large enough, the user should also provide the size of the buffer, in a 3rd argument:

```
char *rArrange(char *orig, char *result, int resultSize)
{
    if (!result || resultSize == 0)
        return NULL;

    /* your code here */

    strncpy(result, arranged, resultSize);
    return result;
}
```

The alternative `malloc()` to store the result is not very user fiendly (the user must freemem() the buffer but may not be aware of this). Using a static/global buffer is not very thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your function `reArrange` returns a pointer to memory that it no longer controls.  The address of the `rearranged` array is returned.  After the return occurs, this array effectively no longer exists -- the memory can, and will, be reused.

A quick hack which fixes your mistake is to declare `rearranged` as `static`.  The long term fix is to learn how C works and code something using `malloc()` or an equivalent.

Comment: Actually in some cases declaring it static is both adequate and safer; not necessarily a `hack`.  If you allocate it dynamically within `reArrange()` you are making the caller responsible for its disposal, so the caller would have to know how it was allocated.  A better (and the most conventional) solution is as detailed by @Rudy Velthuis, then the caller decides on both allocation and disposal, which may or may not be dynamic.  The `static` declaration would make the function non-re-entrant and therefore not thread-safe - as I said "in some cases...".

Comment: @Clifford -- "Actually," declaring it static makes the function non-thread-safe.  Thus, it's a hack -- especially when recommend to an OP who has no idea what is going on.

Comment: Yes it makes it non-thread safe; that is exactly what I said, no argument - I did stress "in some cases" twice.  In many cases thread safety is not an issue; e.g. when  the application is not multi-threaded, or the function is only to be used in a single thread.  The potential for a memory leak will exist with your suggestion in both single and multi-threaded applications.  As I said the best solution is neither of these, but I'd place static allocation ahead of returning a dynamically allocated block.

Answer (score 1):

With `char rearranged[origSize];` you created a new character array which goes out of scope once `reArrange` terminates. So during the lifetime of `reArrange`, `rearranged` is a pointer which points to something meaningful ; hence, `orig = rearranged` makes sense.

But once it goes out of scope, `reArrange(orig)` returns the pointer to `rearranged` which is a dangling pointer now `rearranged` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the following section of the code works?

```
char* reArrange(char* orig) {
  int origSize = strlen(orig);

  char subject[origSize], action[origSize], object[origSize];
```

i mean `origSize` has to be a `const` it can't be a dynamic value. You should use `malloc` for allocating apace for `subject , action and object`. 
Moreover, you might consider a few guidelines:

1 Instead of:

```
for(i = 0; i < origSize; i++) {
    char ch = orig[i];    
    if(ch == SUBJECT) {
      state = SUBJECT;
}
```

You can have:

```
char ch;//declare char ch outside for loop
for(i = 0; i < origSize; i++) {
    ch = orig[i];

    if(ch == SUBJECT) {
      state = SUBJECT;
    }
```

2 you may like to use a `switch` statement instead of `if`, that will make your code look great.

Comment: yeah, that section works. I learned C last summer, and then I quickly forget most non-intuitive ones after one year when I used Java a lot... Truly, switch is better~~

Comment: I'm interested the 1st guideline, what's the reason behind it?